# UIImagePickerController causes duplicate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am implementing a social media application using Swift. In the MyProfileViewController, I have used UIImagePickerController to change the current user's profile picture. However, usage of UIImagePickerController causes a duplicate of table view rows even though I handle the table view in viewDidLoad, not in viewWillAppear.

To illustrate, here is my viewDidLoad function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

    ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).observe(.value, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userId = value?["id"] as! String
        let username = value?["username"] as! String
        let email = value?["userEmail"] as! String
        let profilePictureUrl = value?["profilePicture"] as! String

        self.currentUser = User(id: userId, username: username, email: email, profilePicture: profilePictureUrl)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    ref.child("posts").observe(.childAdded, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let id = value?["id"] as! String
        let tags = value?["tags"] as! String
        let facultyName = value?["faculty"] as! String
        let courseName = value?["course"] as! String
        let questionTitle = value?["title"] as! String
        let questionText = value?["description"] as! String
        let dateAndTime = value?["dateAndTime"] as! String
        let userID = value?["user-id"] as! String

        self.ref.child("users").child(userID).observe(.value, with: {
            (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let userId = value?["id"] as! String
            let username = value?["username"] as! String
            let email = value?["userEmail"] as! String
            let profilePictureUrl = value?["profilePicture"] as! String

            let post = Post(id: id, tags: tags, facultyName: facultyName, courseName: courseName, questionTitle: questionTitle, questionText: questionText, dateAndTime : dateAndTime, username: username)

            if userID == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
            }

            self.postDictionary[id] = post

            let member = User(id: userId, username: username, email: email, profilePicture: profilePictureUrl)

            if post.username == member.username {
                self.userDictionary[id] = member
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })    
}
```

And here is my UIImagePickerController function:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyProfileInfoCell!

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = image
        cell?.profilePicture.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell?.profilePicture.image = image
    }

    var data = NSData()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((cell?.profilePicture.image!)!, 0.8)! as NSData

    let filePath = "\((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)" // path where you wanted to store img in storage
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    self.storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    self.storageRef.child(filePath).putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData) {
        (metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else{
            let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

            self.ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).updateChildValues(["profilePicture" : downloadURL])
        }
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print(self.posts.count)
}
```

My table view consists of 2 prototype cells. The first prototype cell is for the profile information, in which changing profile picture is handled. The second prototype cell is for showing the posts posted by that user. The problem occurs here. When I change my profile picture, the posts rows are being duplicated.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: We cant help without code

Comment: Shared the code. I have tried to be clear, this is my best. Sorry if I am not clear :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observe method adds an observer to "users" on your DB. Every time you changes the "users" on DB the following code is executed and a post is added to tableview:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(userID).observe(.value, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userId = value?["id"] as! String
        let username = value?["username"] as! String
        let email = value?["userEmail"] as! String
        let profilePictureUrl = value?["profilePicture"] as! String

        let post = Post(id: id, tags: tags, facultyName: facultyName, courseName: courseName, questionTitle: questionTitle, questionText: questionText, dateAndTime : dateAndTime, username: username)

        if userID == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
        }

        self.postDictionary[id] = post

        let member = User(id: userId, username: username, email: email, profilePicture: profilePictureUrl)

        if post.username == member.username {
            self.userDictionary[id] = member
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

When you update the profile picture the DB is updated too and the above code is executed. That is why the posts are duplicated. To fix that changes the method from observe to observeSingleEvent. The observeSingleEvent method requests data from DB once.

```
self.ref.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(.value, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userId = value?["id"] as! String
        let username = value?["username"] as! String
        let email = value?["userEmail"] as! String
        let profilePictureUrl = value?["profilePicture"] as! String

        let post = Post(id: id, tags: tags, facultyName: facultyName, courseName: courseName, questionTitle: questionTitle, questionText: questionText, dateAndTime : dateAndTime, username: username)

        if userID == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
        }

        self.postDictionary[id] = post

        let member = User(id: userId, username: username, email: email, profilePicture: profilePictureUrl)

        if post.username == member.username {
            self.userDictionary[id] = member
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```